# Jupyter Notebook cell number is blank after execution

Tags: keras, jupyter-notebook, jupyter, jupyterhub

As you can see [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/knIlJ.png), after I attempt to train my model in this cell, the asterisk disappears and the brackets are blank instead of containing a number. Do you know why this is happening, and how I can fix it? I'm running python 3.7 and TensorFlow 2.5.0.

Comment: The kernel is disconnected.

Answer (score 0):

Your kernel is dead, try to restart the kernel.

Answer (score 0):

Mano is right. Just go to "Kernel", and restart it. Or, you could just O twice. O as in one, not 0.
EDIT:
By the way, it doesn't matter which version of python or tensorflow you have.